# How can I convert jpg or png file to psd with multiple layers?

Tags: css, web-services, psd

I want to convert a png file to a psd file. But how can I get a multiple layer psd file after converting?

Comment: You can't. There's no information available to split the visual elements into separate layers. And even if there was and if you could, there's no guarantee that the PNG, JPG etc. wasn't flattened to a single layer prior to save. Thus thwarting efforts to _"re-layerize" the image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming but rather about image manipulation/conversion.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. PNG files are bitmaps, and do not support layers. PSD files contain metadata that allow them to contain multiple separated layers.